# Is it possible to define an ActiveRecord object based on the results from a .select query on other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an ActiveRecord object based on a complex set of joins, merges, and where clauses. It uses a `.select` statement to create a list of objects with the various IDs of the objects I need to retrieve from the database. The pseudocode below demonstrates: (this is simplified for the the purpose of making the question understandable)

```
list = Foo.joins(:bar).... <etc> ...select("foos.id as foo_id", "bars.id as bar_id")
list.each do |item|
  foo = Foo.find(item.foo_id)
  bar = Bar.find(item.bar_id)
  ... <do something with foo and bar>
end
```

so `list` is an array of Foos with added attributes and accessors for `:foo_id` and `:bar_id`. What I'd like to do is avoid needing to fetch `foo` and `bar` in the loop. So I'm trying to figure out how to create `list` such that I can do the following:

```
list.each do |item|
  foo = item.foo
  bar = item.bar
  ... <do something with foo and bar>
end
```

I'm thinking I need to create a new object with the appropriate associations:

```
class ThingGetter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar

  def self.list
    Foo.joins(:bar).... <etc> ...select("foos.id as foo_id", "bars.id as bar_id")
  end
end

ThingGetter.list.each do |item|
  foo = item.foo
  bar = item.bar
  ... <do something with foo and bar>
end
```

This is close but list is still composed of `Foo`s instead of `ThingGetter`s, so I don't get to use the associations. How do I make list return an ActiveRecord object with a list of `ThingGetter`s?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for SQL views which are stored queries that can be treated like a table. While Rails does not officially support SQL views you can map an ActiveRecord model to a view. https://www.netguru.com/codestories/database-views-and-how-to-use-them-in-a-ror-based-app

Comment: Or maybe what you need is just your standard join model which is what you have in your question. You could just do `ThingGetter.eager_load(:foo, :bar).each do |item| ... end` and Rails will automatically join foos and bars.